# Строка подключение Entity для MSSQL на хостинге

Tags: c#, база-данных, sql-server, mvc, entity

Доброе время суток,
Взял хостинг goodhost.kz, добавил проект и импортировал БД, но не как не могу настроить строку подключение.
мой код:

```
providerName="System.Data.EntityClient"
connectionString="metadata=res://*/ ContextClass.csdl|res://*/ ContextClass.ssdl|res://*/ ContextClass.msl;provider=System.Data.SqlClient;provider connection string=&quot;Data Source=178.89.186.221;Integrated Security=False;User Id=administrator;Password=123456789;MultipleActiveResultSets=True&quot;" />
```

Мои действия:
Добавил строку вылезает ошибка, сайт открывается но данные из БД, не поступают, на странице выходит сообщение " Ошибка. При обработке запроса произошла ошибка."

так же, я подключился к БД через Visual Studio программу, посмотрел через свойства строку подключение, она выглядет так: Provider=SQLNCLI11;Data Source=178.89.186.221,1434;User ID=administrator;Initial Catalog=jobdb добавил вместо той строки, эту строку, но опять ошибка, даже после User ID=administrator;password=parol4ik все равно ошибка, в чем может быть проблема хз

База Данных MSSQL. Пожалуйста помогите.

Comment: `не как не могу настроить` - расшифруйте, пожалуйста. У вас ошибка возникает (какая?), или что происходит?

Comment: да ошибка происходит, сайт открывается но данные из БД, не поступают, на странице выходит сообщение " Ошибка. При обработке запроса произошла ошибка."

Comment: так же, я подключился к БД через Visual Studio программу, посмотрел через свойства строку подключение, она выглядет так:   Provider=SQLNCLI11;Data Source=178.89.186.221,1434;User ID=administrator;Initial Catalog=jobdb добавил вместо той строки, эту строку, но опять ошибка, даже после User ID=administrator;password=parol4ik все равно ошибка, в чем может быть проблема хз

Comment: Добавьте эту информацию в вопрос и оформите пожалуйста так, чтобы было удобно читать. Тогда будет больше шанс получить полезный ответ.

Answer (score 0):

Ребят решил проблему методом тыка как говорится,

1. создал файл тхт с расширением .udl
2. подключился сохранил ТХТ, открыл сам ТХТ файл, скопировал строку, далее, добавил строку в вебконфиг на хостинге,

Provider=SQLOLEDB.1;Password=Парольчик;Persist Security Info=True;User ID=administrator;Initial Catalog=jobdb;Data Source=178.89.186.221,1434
Он все равно не заработал. но удалив строку Provider=SQLOLEDB.1; и проверив, все заработало! надеюсь кому то это инфа будет полезна. е*№лся целый день!